# Lift MetaProtoStateMachine does not take type parameters

Tags: scala, lift

I am trying to implement lift state machine following lift-in-action book using lift 2.5 and scala 2.10

```
import net.liftweb.common.{Loggable,Full,Empty}
import net.liftweb.machine.{ProtoStateMachine,MetaProtoStateMachine}
import net.liftweb.mapper.MappedLongForeignKey
import net.liftweb.util.Helpers._

object AuctionStates extends Enumeration {
  val Initial, Active, Expired = Value
}

object AuctionMachine extends AuctionMachine with MetaProtoStateMachine[AuctionMachine, AuctionStates.type ]{
...
}

class AuctionMachine extends ProtoStateMachine[AuctionMachine, AuctionStates.type]{
  def getSingleton = AuctionMachine
...
}
```

however I am getting this error
error:

```
net.liftweb.machine.MetaProtoStateMachine does not take type parameters

[INFO] object AuctionMachine extends AuctionMachine with MetaProtoStateMachine[AuctionMachine, AuctionStates.type]
```

why?

Comment: Are you using right version of Lift framework? I can not find `MetaProtoStateMachine` in docs for 2.3+ versions, only in Lift 2.2.

Comment: @chemikadze is it removed or changed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code was moved out of Lift proper into a Lift module in 2012.  You can find more info on how to properly reference it here: https://github.com/liftmodules/machine